MuJoCo Simulation disassembles itself - the joints aren't held to the main body
I am currently working on a project that requires me to use premade meshes from SolidWorks to simulate an arm in MuJoCo. Here is my code so far:
<mujoco model="RX-5001-V005-Defeatured">
    <compiler angle="degree" />
    <option timestep="0.01"/>
    <visual>
        <headlight ambient="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
    </visual>

    <asset>
        <mesh name="base" file="Base Defeatured.STEP-1.obj" />
        <mesh name="ab" file="AB Defeatured.STEP-1.obj" />
        <mesh name="rxclaw" file="RX-1049 part.STEP-1.obj" />
        <mesh name="longtube" file="Long Tube Defeatured.STEP-1.obj" />
        <mesh name="joint1" file="Joint Defeatured.STEP-1.obj" />
        <mesh name="joint2" file="Joint Defeatured.STEP-2.obj" />
        <mesh name="joint3" file="Joint Defeatured.STEP-3.obj" />
        <mesh name="joint4" file="Joint Defeatured.STEP-4.obj" />
        <mesh name="joint5" file="Joint Defeatured.STEP-5.obj" />
    </asset>
    <worldbody>


        <body name="base" pos="0 0 0" euler="0 180 0">
            <geom type="mesh" mesh="base" />
        <body name="joint4" euler="0 0 0">
                <geom type="mesh" mesh="joint4" />
                <joint name="joint4" type="hinge" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 0 1" />
        
        <body name="longtube" pos="0 0 0" euler="0 0 0">
                <geom type="mesh" mesh="longtube" />
            <body name="joint3" euler="0 0 0">
                <geom type="mesh" mesh="joint3" />
                <joint name="joint3" type="hinge" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 1 0"/>
            </body>
            <body name="joint5" euler="0 0 0">
                    <geom type="mesh" mesh="joint5" />
                    <joint name="joint5" type="hinge" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 1 0" />
            </body>

            </body>
            </body>
        </body>

<!--Joint 2 + AB, and Joint 3 fly off-->

    <body name="joint2" euler="0 180 0">
            <geom type="mesh" mesh="joint2" />
            <joint name="joint2" type="hinge" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 0 1" />
        <body name="ab" pos="0 0 0" euler="0 0 0">
            <geom type="mesh" mesh="ab" />
        <body name="joint1" euler="0 0 0">
                <geom type="mesh" mesh="joint1" />
                <joint name="joint1" type="hinge" pos="0 0 0" axis="0 0 1" />
            <body name="rxclaw" pos="0 0 0" euler="0 0 0">
                    <geom type="mesh" mesh="rxclaw" />
                </body>
            </body>
            </body>
        </body>

    </worldbody>

</mujoco>

When this is loaded, the arm looks how it should: model when loaded in
However, when I unpause the simulation, the joints all start moving:
Joints are flying
What could be the reason why my model is falling apart?
I've tried reducing the friction between the bodies, but that was to no avail. My GUI for the MuJoCo simulator isn't visible on the side, but sometimes when I run the simulation, a green outline which I assume is the hitboxes of each mesh is visible and I can see that they are all touching or inside another hitbox. Would this be the source of my problem (the original alignment of the mesh file itself?).

It turns out that my mesh files itself were not properly imported (they had a center that wasn't on itself, but rather somewhere random in space.) I just exported each mesh into blender and recentered them, and then when I imported the meshes the simulation worked as expected.
